# 私にしたから in きっとあんな事を私にしたから

Tags: particle-に

> （……それは、きっとあんな事を私にしたから……）

speaker wants to quit for a good reason but was just given a compliment/great news that can't be ignored

i look at this as: "that(good result) is definitely because of what i did"

though that requires some gymnastics to get there. A を B に (して) does not seem to apply, so  rearranging as:

私にあんな事をしたから, in certain situation に can be used to mark the cause of something (「病に倒れる」「日に焼ける」「風にそよぐ」), but not with a direct object and transitive verb and  following it.

Shoehorning this as some variant of ～にすれば, ～にしたら, ～にしてみれば doesn't really fit either

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about such a basic grammar point that I am not entirely sure if I am reading your question correctly.

> 「私**が/は**した」 = "I did something."
>
> 「私**に**した」 = "Someone did something to/for me"

The two phrases above mean completely different things from each other. **In the second, the subject is unmentioned**.  The particles, the shortest- and simplest-looking words in Japanese, have that kind of power.

> （……それは、きっとあんな事を私**に**したから……）

therefore, means:

> "That is because (someone) did/has done such a thing to me."

Are you following this?  Once again, that "someone" is unmentioned here, but thanks to the particle 「に」, we know for sure that 「私」 is ***not*** the action-taker.

The 「私」 is the indirect object and the 「あんな事」, the direct object.

For this reason, your interpretation:

"**that(good result) is definitely because of what i did**"

is off.  It is another person, not the speaker him/herself, who has done あんな事.

Finally, as you said, the expressions ～にすれば, ～にしたら and ～にしてみれば have absolutely nothing to do with what we are discussing here.

Comment: i think it was an issue of how long the あんな事 wasn't mentioned in perspective of the doer in this case. Past several lines of conversation was about how happy that doer was because of the speaker. So naturally you would think that it was something the speaker did. However if you put it this way, the doer could also have been was so happy because of the fact the he got to "do it" (harass).

Comment: i suppose more accurately since the person the speaker is talking to has has no idea what  the person in question has done, anything that the person did was never brought up.

Answer (score 0):

It means that’s probably because he/she/they/you did such a thing to me.
It may be like he/she/they/you told a lie to “me” or ignored “me” and after that he/she/they/you felt sorry or another person hated him/her/them/you.
But I know this doesn’t suit the context.
At least, 病に倒れる and 〜にすれば have nothing to do with this sentence.